# Create App Service Managed Certificates by Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I want to create certification by App Service Managed Certificate.
I set these records
[image: records]

and it works correctly but when I want to create App Service Managed Certificates by Azure
I got a strange error

```
Failed to create App Service Managed Certificate for hostname. Click here for more details.
```

[image: error]

I try different CAA records and none of them works.
what should I do?

and if I want to use terraform it is stuck at creating the certificate
I use this [template](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service_certificate_binding)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure does not support the .ir domain.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27927135)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet: I believe Yassin is saying that is the answer: That Azure throws this error because, apparently, it doesn’t support the `.ir` TLD for managed certificates.

Comment: @yasin lachini. Do you have some article or official words to support this? If yes, please post the link or screenshot. Thank you for sharing.

Comment: because of sanction of iran Azure does not support .ir domain

Answer (score 1):

Good news on App service managed certificate.
Yes, you heard correctly it became GA now and supports apex domain with a country code top-level domain (ccTLD).

Key Features:

1. Supports Apex domain.
2. Auto renewed.
3. Expired in 6 month.
4. Auto renew 45 days before expiration.
5. Automate using ARM template.
6. App Service Managed Certificate for apex domain will take a bit longer to create than for sub-domain because it uses a different validation method.
7. Not exportable.

I hope this will help you in securing your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the tutorial you need is this:

[map-a-cname-record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-a-cname-record)

[Create a free certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#create-a-free-certificate-preview)

---

I had seen this error before, and solve it by the steps below:

1. Check the CNAME records. Map a subdomain to the app's default domain name needs two records: CNAME record and TXT record.
   [image]
2. Make sure you enabled the CNAME record mapping in Azure .
   [image]
3. Clear the records you don't need, like the CAA records, because wildcard certificatesis not support for [creating a free certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#create-a-free-certificate-preview). Take care of the limitations.
4. It may takes a while for this configuration to take effect.

Comment: I add TXT record and delete CAA but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

App Service Managed Certificate is still in Preview, there are some limitations with this (as of today), kindly check them below.
It's a private certificate to use if you just need to secure your **www** custom domain or any non-naked domain in App Service.

The free certificate is issued by DigiCert. For some top-level domains, you must explicitly allow DigiCert as a certificate issuer by creating a CAA domain record with the value: 0 issue digicert.com.

The free certificate comes with the following limitations:

- Does not support wildcard certificates.
- Does not support naked domains.
- Is not exportable.
- Is not supported on App Service Environment (ASE)
- Does not support A records. For example, automatic renewal doesn't work with A records.

Kindly see the different between App Service Certificate and App Service Managed Certificate.
https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip259.html

[image]

Checkout [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#create-a-free-certificate-preview) for more details.

Comment: How can I solve my issue?
I use www   and it should not have any problem

Comment: I also create  CAA domain record with the value: 0 issue digicert.com.